# boot0ss: error // Just after installing Ubuntu 20.04 and rebooting

Tags: boot, 20.04

Once I have installed Ubuntu, when I reboot the system, I got a black screen that only says:

**boot0ss: error**

I have tried to install several times, but nothing works. Haven't find this issue on forum.

I can't boot...

Anyone knows what it can be?

***Installation details:***

I created the media for installation using BalenaEtcher on a Mac.  Have tried to different devices to make the bootable image, but same problem.

I'm trying to install it on an old desktop, components:

- MSI z77
- i7 2600k
- 8GB RAM (2x4GB DDR3 1600)
- The bootable drive I'm using is a Goldenfir SSD 500GB connected via SATA port.
- I have another 2 x HDDs 500GB connected via sata

For the installation I've just selected Delete drive and install Ubuntu.

Thanks!!

Comment: Where are you trying to install Ubuntu? Hardware specification, make/model... How did you make the installation media? Please edit the question to add info. Ping me @ChanganAuto when done.

Comment: Old(ish) but new enough to have UEFI instead of BIOS. Please check settings in UEFI ("BIOS") and confirm the boot mode is UEFI, not UEFI+Legacy. This assures the installation media boots and installs in the correct (preferred) mode. Then open Gparted in the live session and blank the target drive by creating a new partition table GPT (Devices menu > Create... > GPT), no need to do anything else to the other drives, only to one where you intend to install Ubuntu. Install as you normally would. This assures the best, recommended, settings. (...)

Comment: (...) If it still fails then the SSD drive probably needs its firmware updated. And also update UEFI ("BIOS") to the latest if not done already (latest release is from 2013). Keep us posted. If successfull then I might turn into an answer.

Comment: @ChanganAuto done and solved! Actually was only needed to check UEFI settings, I restored it and confirmed the boot mode is UEFI. Tried to directly boot Ubuntu and everything worked fine, so, probably was something else I had misconfigured in BIOS. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome. Well, giving that you solved it yourself, why don't you post it as answer? You can later accept it and get points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @ChanganAuto advice I just went to BIOS and restore everything to default values. Then I made sure the boot mode is UEFI. Finally, I also checked the booting drives order, to make sure the desired drive is in the first place.

Probably was just something misconfigured. Wasn't necessary to reinstall ubuntu.

If you have same problem and reseting BIOS doesn't solve it, just follow Changan's comment, probably it's helpful to you.